# Tag that wraps another tag in grails?

Tags: grails, gsp

I wish to write a tag that can "wrap" a child tag and **always** pass all of its attributes to this child tag. So, that any attributes that are passed into the parent tag, get passed down to the child. The idea is to produce a tag that can "decorate" multiple *different* child tags and thus extend their functionality without changing existing tags.

Is this possible in grails?

A rough outline of the idea:

```
// taglib

def parentTag = { attrs, body ->
    out << "<div class='parent'></div>"
}
def childTag1 = { attrs, body -> 
    // code
}
def childTag2 = { attrs, body ->
    // code
}
```

In the .gsp:

```
// view
<mytaglib:ParentTag attr1="hello" attr2="world">
    </mytaglib:childTag1>
</mytaglib:ParentTag

<mytaglib:ParentTag attr1="hello" attr2="world">
    </mytaglib:childTag2>
</mytaglib:ParentTag
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div attr1="hello" attr2="world"></div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>
    <div attr1="hello" attr2="world"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you basically can do that. this example should do the stuff you expect it to:

```
def parentTag = {attrs, body ->
  // do your decoration stuff
  out << "<div>"

  // call the child tag
  out << childTag(attrs, body)

  // do your decoration stuff
  out << "</div>"
}

def childTag = {attrs, body ->
  out << "<div attr1='" + attrs['attr1'] + "' attr2='" + attrs['attr2'] + "'></div>"
}
```

Comment: This would only work for one specific child tag "childTag". I want to use it to decorate multiple _different_ child tags.

Comment: oh, ok i see. that would require a little more parsing of the body attribute i would guess. Perhaps you take a look at the [decorator plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/decorator) to give you a good starting point.